# Create a video with other videos at certain points

Tags: node.js, video, ffmpeg

I've never used ffmpeg before, and I need to do something quite complicated (in my opinion at least, this could be easy).

Basically I need to have a black video but at certain points concatenate other videos.
For example, at 0.00 a 3 second video, then black until 10.0 and then another video, etc etc

The finished videos will consist of hundreds of videos and be anywhere from 1-5 minutes long.

I'm working in Node.js, ideally using a wrapper would be best (I'm using fluent-ffmpeg currently but any will suffice), although raw commands are also an option.

Any ideas are appreciated!

Edit: also, say a 5 second video is at 0.00, and a 10 second video is at 1.00, I'd like it to overwrite the original 5 second video

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question.

Could you clarify these points:

1. Multiple videos with different duration
2. black filler **always** between 2 videos?
3. black filler duration always the same or variable?
4. How would you conveniently set variable durations for the black filler for hundreds of them?
5. Who sets up that **video X** starts at 0.00 and **video Y** at 1.00, overwriting video X?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, basically say I have an array of videos with time points for each, like `[[0.00, "test.mp4"], ["1.00, "test1.mp4"]]`, say `test.mp4` is 4 minutes long and `test1.mp4` is 1 minute long, I need it so that it inputs test1.mp4 at 0.00 and then at 1.00 it stops test.mp4 and starts test1.mp4. To sum it up it needs to make a black video a certain length (already have that part done) and then insert those other videos from the array onto the black video at those specific time points, overwriting existing videos if they overlap. I'm not sure how to explain this, sorry

Comment: If the overwrite existing idea isn't possible, I also have start/end points for each video if that's easier.